# Fatal error: Class 'Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary' not Found in WordPress

Tags: installation, fatal-error

While installing the WordPress in the server I am getting below error.

> Fatal error: Class 'Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary' not
>   found in public_html/wp-includes/Requests/Response/Headers.php on line
>   13

Can any one suggest some solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume it's a clean installation so I can think of two things:

- The upload (installation) wasn't complete
- Some file permissions are not correct (folders: 755, files: 644)

I'd firstly try to remove all core files and re-upload everything.